# Substitutes the prices of commodities in the admin. magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products-management

I would be grateful for all the help.

I need to catch an event that brings the Manage Products in the table price.
Regardless of the price in the database, you need to display a different price.

Price is taken dynamically via XML with other resources.

For the frontend, I decided this through events
`catalog_product_get_final_price` and `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

But what event could be used to substitute the price of goods in the admin can not find.

Prompt who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will come in handy.
I used the event `catalog_product_save_after`. 
That's part of the code:

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                    <admin_update_price>
                        <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updateProductPrice</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </admin_update_price>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

Observer.php

```
 public function updateProductPrice($observer)
   {  
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $price = 10;
    $product->setPrice($price);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
   }
```

This is an example of code that works for me.